# Triggering an event when a class is removed from a element via jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code that uses jquery to remove a class from a `<div>`. Is it possible via events to trigger another jquery function when a class is removed?

html

```
<div class="square"></div> <br/>
<div class="square test"></div><br/>
<div class="square"></div> <br/>
<div class="square"></div>
<button>test</button>
```

css

```
.square{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
}
.pink{
background-color:pink;
}
```

javascript

```
$(document).on("*changedtopink*", "div", function(){
   alert("it changed");
});
$(document).on("click","button",function(){
   $(".test").addClass("pink");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) your own event:

**HTML**

```
<div class="square"></div> <br/>
<div class="square"></div> <br/>
<div class="square"></div> <br/> 
<div class="square"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.square{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.rectangle{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("div").on("changedClass", function(){
    $(this).addClass("rectangle");
});

$(document).on("click", "div", function(){
    $(this).removeClass("square");               
    $(this).trigger("changedClass");
});
```

Clicking on a red square in this example will remove the `.square` class and trigger my newly defined  `changedClass` event. This event fires for the given `div` and adds a new class or `.rectangle`.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/9nYyJ/1/)**

**EDIT**:

**HTML**

```
<div class="square"></div> <br/>
<div class="square"></div> <br/>
<div class="square"></div> <br/> 
<div class="square"></div>  
<input type="hidden" value="N" />
```

**jQuery**

```
//When the input is changed, add the rectangle class
$("input").on("change", function(e, divEl){
    $(divEl).addClass("rectangle");
});

//when a div is clicked, trigger a change event for the input place holder.
$(document).on("click", "div", function(){             
    $("input").trigger("change", [this]);
});


//regualr click event for your div
$(document).on("click", "div", function(){             
    $(this).removeClass("square");
});
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/9nYyJ/3/)**

and here's one more **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/9nYyJ/4/)** that uses a button.

Comment: I see how I can trigger it on a click or mouseover type of event but can I trigger it when some other jquery function removes a class?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're trying to accomplish? Is there not a way for you to modify your code so that the `trigger` code is within your function that removes the class?

Comment: The piece that I am working on is terribly convoluted that is why I'm trying to find a way using events.  I will see if I can put together a way stripped down sample.

Comment: @JohnS, I'm looking at your example, is there no way you can simply insert one extra line into your click event to `trigger` the new event?

Comment: @JohnS - Alright, I'm updating my code with another example. It's probably not the best way to do it, but it may work in your case. I've added 2 new examples, one of which uses a button as you suggested in your example.

Answer (score 0):

There are Dom Change events, but not widely supported by all browsers. I think the safest approach, if it is suitable in your use case, is to check for the class on a timer, and run a function when you detect the class changes.

```
var hasClass = false;

setInterval(function(){
  if($('#selector').hasClass('myClass') != hasClass){
    hasClass = $('#selector').hasClass('myClass')
    // fun your custom function here
  }
},100)
```

Comment: Isn't this a bad practice? If one needs more than one event.. it will have  timers all over the place..

Comment: Its a simple quick solution when we need it just for a couple of elements on a page. The timer could be set to 500ms or more so its a bit less heavy on browsers.

Answer (score -1):

The correct (standards track) way to do this in the year 2021 is to use a MutationObserver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Read the above link and then when you call `observer.observe()` you pass in a set of options as the second parameter - if you pass in `{attributes: true}` as your options, the mutation observer will watch for all attribute changes on the relevant element. Since `class` is an attribute, your mutation observer will fire off its callback when a class is added or removed from the element - simply check the elements `classList` from within the callback to filter for the class you want.

More on how to use MutationObserver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver